# Raster to shapefile results in polygons with no difference in values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to convert a 32bit floating point raster in tiff format to a vector .shp file in ArcMap. In particular, I have been attempting to convert my continuous data set found in the TIFF extension into a shapefile. The data contains bluespot depths.

I tried Raster to Polygon but the output gave a polygon with no difference in values. How can I get the values into the shapefile?

Comment: the tiff has 32 bit depth and the datatype is floating point.

i want to add some of these bluespots as barriers in my network analysis thats why i want to have them as a shapefile. Any other suggestion to do this is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Esri Technical Support article, "How To: Convert a floating type raster to a polygon feature class and retain the decimal values", outlines converting floating type rasters to polygons.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012554

The solution provided requires a Spatial Analyst license, and basically involves multiplying the raster values to remove decimal places.

The general instructions on that page are:

> 1. Using the Raster Calculator tool, multiply the raster with a multiple of 10 required to remove the decimal values. For example,
>      multiply a raster by 1000 if the raster values contain three decimal
>      places, and by 100 if the values contain two decimal places.
> 2. Using the Int tool, convert the floating type raster to an integer type raster.
> 3. Convert the integer type raster to a polygon feature class using the Raster to Polygon tool.
> 4. Divide the polygon feature class by the multiple of 10 used in Step 1 to get the original decimal values.